# Creating a static table header

Tags: php

I know there are lots of plugins there to display a table with static headers. My issue is that i have a for loop which returns the values under this table:

```
foreach($ftsProducts as $x) {

    $content .= "<tr class='highlight'>

                    <td class='reportCell' title='" . $x['BaseCode'] . "'>" . $x['Description'] . "</td>

                    <td class='reportCell'>" . $x['Fit'] . "</td>";

                    foreach($sizes as $y) {

                        $content .= "<td class='reportCell'>" . $x[$y] . "</td>";

                    }

                    $content .= "<td style='font-weight: bold; text-align: center;'>" . $x['Total'] . "</td>

                </tr>";

}

$content .= "</table>";
```

Anyone got any suggestions or advice.

Many thanks

Comment: What exactly is the issue? If the issue is having a loop, remove it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what your problem is? Can you elaborate what you think should be happening that isn't?

Comment: Simply output the headers outside of the loop which outputs the underlying rows...no?

Comment: I need to find a  way to make the following cells static.

Comment: But what do you mean by 'static'?

Comment: so when i scroll down the columns fit and descript stay static.

Comment: I'm really sorry - you're not helping explain what you want to happen, or what you've tried that hasn't so far worked

Answer (score 2):

As far as i understand, your problem is not related to PHP, but to HTML and CSS. Static headers are tricky to achieve and there are probably browsers, which won't let you do them. Have a look at this solution, for example:

http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

By viewing the source of the page, it should -- imo -- be obvious how you have to build your table with PHP.

HTH